# Can't plot value counts for pie chart

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pie-chart, subplot

I wrote a function to plot the distribution of values for variables in a pie chart, as shown below.  [image: Pie chart I need to get]

```
def draw_piecharts(df, variables, n_rows, n_cols):
     df[variables].value_counts.plot(kind='pie', layout=(n_rows,n_cols), subplots=True)
     plt.show()
def main():
    util.draw_piecharts(df, [ 'TARGET', 'BanruptcyInd'], 1,2)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Unfortunately my function doesn't compute because dataframes have no attribute `value_counts()`, and value_counts is the only way I know how to get the distribution plotted in a pie chart. 
Here's a sample of the variables being plotted:

```
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     0
9     0
10    0
11    0
12    1
13    0
14    0
15    0
16    0
17    1
18    0
19    0
20    0
21    1
22    0
23    0
24    1
25    0
26    1
27    0
28    0
29    0
Name: TARGET, dtype: int64
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     0
9     0
10    0
11    0
12    0
13    0
14    0
15    0
16    0
17    0
18    0
19    0
20    0
21    0
22    0
23    0
24    0
25    0
26    0
27    0
28    0
29    0
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While `value_counts` is a Series method, it's easily applied to the Series inside DataFrames by using `DataFrame.apply`. In your case. for example,

```
df[variables].apply(pd.value_counts).plot(kind='pie', layout=(n_rows,n_cols), subplots=True)
```

(assuming `pandas` has been imported as `pd`).

For a complete example:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1],'b': [1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]})
a.apply(pd.value_counts).plot.pie(subplots=True)
```